# What will happen if there is a way predicting at a least one root of $p_{n}(x)=0$ without calculator?

Tags: polynomials, roots, predicate-logic

let $p_{n}(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ defined as follow :

$p_{n}(x)=x^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+.....a_{0}$ which :

$a_{n-1},a_{n-2},.....,a_{0}$ are non nul real numbers coefficients.

my question is : What will happen if there is a way  predicting at a least one root of $p_{n}(x)=0$ without calculator?

Any help is very welcom.Thank you

Comment: In the most general case? No, there isn't. In quite a few *particular cases* you can, of course.

Comment: Where do the coefficients come from? Real numbers? A field? Complex numbers? Who knows.

Comment: is there any proof for this ?

Comment: sorry , fixy typo

Comment: If you could find one root, then you could factor it out.  Then if you could find one root, you could factor it out.  Then if you could find one root...

Comment: the problem is how i find not factorisation

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Antonio Vargas's point is that such an ability, in general, would lead to a complete factorization of all finite polynomials, which is not possible for quintics and higher.  For instance, suppose you have a polynomial $p_5(x)$.  You use some algorithm and find a root $x_1$.  You can now factor $p_5(x) = (x-x_1)p_4(x)$.  You apply the same algorithm and find a root $x_2$ of $p_4(x)$ to get $p_5(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)p_3(x)$.  And so on.

Comment: Since we know this cannot be done in general, there can be no general way to do what you propose, in general, either.  In isolated cases, it may be possible, but without restricting your question to those isolated cases, it's impossible to say what can be done.

Comment: yes , it's still impossible and i edited the question

Comment: I am not sure if I have well understood your question. According I have understood, a way is take two values of x for which one of f(x) is positive and the other negative (with this "method" no matter of degree > than 3,4 or 5 or more)

Comment: @so give us your method as answer , and thank you luis Gomez

Comment: This is just for the existence of at least one root (possibly more) between the two values of x. The corresponding determination is quite another thing.